# function (with variable) -> function -> fat arrow function- >variable from first function showing here?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

I am learning about lexical `this` being passed around and it is my understanding that a fat arrow gets its "this" from itself or the function above it. If that is a regular function my understanding is it wouldn't get `this` from a function higher than this. For example this is the code I believe shouldn't run:

```js
function test() {
  this.a = 5; // test()' variable
  this.b = function() {
    //this is a fat arrow function so console log below could grab the this from this function's space, but not higher than this, but it does?
    this.c = setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(this.a);
    }, 1000);
  }
}
var d = new test();
d.b();
```

So I expect that the console.log statement wants to print out `this.a` . It doesn't exist in the fat arrow functions context so it goes up one level to the anonymous function level. There is also no `this.a` here. This is a regular non-fat arrow function meaning the lexical scope to my understanding should stop here, it shouldn't go up any higher, but it does and I am not sure why. Why is this happening?

Comment: `var d = new test();` is the root execution context i believe. And lexical scope lookup eventually finds the variable `a`

Comment: The b function is a part of/attached to test, they have the same this pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're invoking the function b as `d.b` it's `this` is object `d`. So `this.a` is equivalent to `d.a`. As you already observe, the arrow function will carry `this` from its parent scope, hence it is able to resolve `this.a` as `d.a`.

```js
function test() {

  this.a = 5; // test()' variable
  this.b = function() {
    console.log("this.a in b: ", this.a);
  
    this.c = setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("this.a in c: ", this.a);
    }, 1000);
  }
}

var d = new test();
d.b();
```

---

What happens if you pull `d.b` in a separate variable, and then invoke it? You get `undefined` - because `this` inside `b` now refers to the global scope.

```js
function test() {

  this.a = 5; // test()' variable
  this.b = function() {
    console.log("this.a in b: ", this.a);
    console.log("this === window: ",this === window);
  
    this.c = setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("this.a in c:", this.a);
    }, 1000);
  }
}

var d = new test();
var myNewFunction = d.b;

myNewFunction();
```

Answer (score 1):

read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) (pun intended)

"When a function is called as a method of an object, its `this` is set to the object the method is called on"

Consider this simplified example:

```js
"use strict";

var obj = {
  name: "obj",
  a: function() {
    return this
  }
}
var a = obj.a
var obj2 = {
  name: "obj2"
}
obj2.a = a

console.log(
  obj.a(), // => obj
  a(), // => window | undefined (based on strict mode)
  obj2.a() // => obj2
)
```

Similarly, in your example, calling `d.b()` will set `this` to `d` inside `b`. Inside your arrow function, this context will be preserved.